# How to remove Antonio carraro tire desk?

Tags: tractor

I am trying to remove tire desk or whatever the part name is, I am guessing that there is some special tool that I don't have to do that, I am afraid to use brute Force and break something, or should I just use a hammer?[image]

Comment: Is that a drum brake?

Comment: The image is not very clear, but it looks as though you need an [h-bar style puller](http://www.spxflow.com/en/images/full11_14376Pullers_7393_Gear_and_Pulley.jpg). I cannot tell if the two holes on the side are threaded or not (the holes just off of the main shaft which are at 4 and 10 o'clock). If this is threaded, this is definitely what you'd use. If they are not threaded, I really don't have a clue.

Answer (score 1):

You have four bolt holes in a line, you need to get or make a puller the uses the centre point on the shaft and the two bolt holes closest to the shaft to pull the plate off.

Do Not use a hammer and smack the sh1t out of it as then the shaft increases in diameter and won’t pass through the hole in the plate.

If you make one then you need some strong plate or angle otherwise it just bends...

Edit: given that the part is located with a woodruff key (you can see the key in the slot...) then it is not likely to be a taper fit and should come off relatively easily.

Comment: So basically to remove it I need to appl one helluva pull force, after all I have to make the tool...

Comment: No, a relatively small force correctly and evenly applied works fine... A lot of force applied incorrectly ....

Comment: Soak it a few days with liberal amounts of penetrant.